# Incredibly difficult Python type annotation error

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

The following code involving generic subclasses fails to typecheck:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Generic, Tuple, Type, TypeVar

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B', bound='W')


class W(Generic[A]):

    @classmethod
    def g(cls: Type[B]) -> B:
        return cls()


class X(W[A], Generic[A]):

    C = TypeVar('C', bound='X.Y')  # I really want X[A].Y here.

    class Y(W[Tuple[A, A]]):

        @classmethod
        def g(cls: Type[X.C]) -> X.C:
            return super().g()
```

I've obviously made a mistake, but I don't understand the error:

`error: Return type "Y[A]" of "g" incompatible with return type "Y[Tuple[A, A]]" in supertype "W"`

Comment: `W.g` won't take an arbitrary class `B` as an argument; it will always be `W` (or a subclass of `W`).

Comment: Without more detail, there's no need to define `Y.g`; with `W.g` defined, a call to `Y.g()` will call `W.g` with `Y` as its argument.

Comment: @chepner I understand your desire for detail.  I have the full example [here](https://github.com/NeilGirdhar/fax_suggestions/blob/master/cmm/fixed_point/combinator.py).  I thought I would make the question as simple as possible.